# Any difference between '+' and '&' for String concatenation?

Tags: string, vba

I have very recently realized that VBA supports also the operator `+` to concatenate `String` type, and not only `&`.
Hence, if

```
Dim a As String, b As String
a = "Stack "
b = "Overflow"
```

the following statements will produce the same result:

```
>> a + b '--> "Stack Overflow"
>> a & b '--> "Stack Overflow"
```

In my limited experience I have never found in any language two operators doing **always** the same thing. I feel like VBA is tending to merge to other common languages (using only `+` for concatenating strings) but still supporting the `&` for old-school VB developers.

But this doesn't sound much as a technical explanation, so I'd like to ask the following question: *is there any practical difference between the two operators? Does a case where using `+` rather than `&` yields a different result?*

### What I have in mind

A possible "like-answer" that I have in mind but cannot find anywhere in the web was inspired by JavaScript, where you can use the `==` and `===` almost everywhere with the same behavior, except that *The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.*

Comment: I am not sure about VBA, but in some other/older versions of Basic, using `+` on strings would result in it checking to see if they were numeric-text strings, and if so, it would convert them to numbers, add them and then convert them back.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I thought the same, but if `a = "1"` and `b = "2"`, doing `a+b` or `a & b` would result both in `"12"`. So I don't think it's related to this, even if it would have been reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found it.  Try this:

```
Debug.Print "3" + 4 '--> 7
```

and compare it to this:

```
Debug.Print "3" & 4 '--> "34"
```

Ahh! See the difference now?  The choice of `&` vs. `+` affects what the default type it coerces the operands of these expressions to.

The `+` will try to convert the `String` in `Numeric` and, if possible, will treat them as such. The `&`, on the other hand, will keep treating the elements as `String` even if they're both convertible in `Numeric`.